NextJS Typescript - Object is possibly undefined - nextjs build failure
I am new to typescript and have been stuck in nextjs build. The code code runs perfectly in my browser but when I try to execute nextjs build I am getting the below error. I tried a few methods after looking up online but no success. I am calling test function on click of a button.
Type error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

  62 |     useEffect(() => {
  63 |         if(value!.includes('javascript')){
> 64 |             setJs(value!.split('```javascript').pop().split('```')[0])
     |                   ^
  65 |         }
  66 |
  67 |         if (value!.includes('html')){

CODE:
const [value, setValue] = useState<string|null>('const pi = 3.14;');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [html, setHtml]=useState('')
    const [css,setCss] = useState('')
    const [js,setJs] = useState('')


    useEffect(() => {
        if(value!.includes('javascript')){
            setJs(value!.split('```javascript').pop().split('```')[0])
        }

        if (value!.includes('html')){
            setHtml(value!.split('```html').pop().split('```')[0])
        }

        if (value!.includes('css')){
            setCss(value!.split('```css').pop().split('```')[0])
        }
    },[value])





    const test = async () => {


        try {

            setValue('hi')


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


With const [value, setValue] = useState<string|null>('const pi = 3.14;');  you are telling typescript that value might be null. Since you are never setting it to null, you can safely change useState<string | null> to useState<string>.
And since value!.split('```javascript').pop().split('```')[0] might be undefined, you can either change it to value.split('```javascript').pop()?.split('```')[0] ?? '' making use of the nullish coalescing operator or change it to value.split('```javascript').pop().split('```')[0] and adjust 'js' state's type to const [js,setJs] = useState<string | undefined>('')
You can also remove the ! when accessing the value variable. With ! you are telling the typescript compiler: "hey this can't be undefined or null, so don't complain about the possibility".

Either that, or change the !.split to ?.split so it can return undefined on a nested or returned value... but you'd have to add this notation to the rest of the methods in that line. The idea way though is to check if your value exists before doing something with it anyways. If you know for sure that you'll never set the value to null or undefined, take ^Daves approach.

tried both approaches. Still the same error on the same line.
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('const pi = 3.14;');

useEffect(() => {
if(value?.includes('javascript')){
setJs(value?.split('javascript').pop().split('')[0])
}
    if (value!.includes('html')){
        setHtml(value!.split('```html').pop().split('```')[0])
    }

    if (value!.includes('css')){
        setCss(value!.split('```css').pop().split('```')[0])
    }
},[value])```


Remove the ? and since pop() returns string|undefined use optional accessing ? and  then make use of the nullish coalescing operator ??.
E.g.: setJs(value.split('```javascript').pop()?.split('```')[0] ?? "")

There is possibility that the value may be null at some point. But right now I am just trying to get the next build to succeed. adding in my tsconfig file too. Why is the non-null assertion not working? I would think that. would remove the error.
